# Why are the formulas for magnetic or electric fluxes as such?

Tags: electromagnetism

For electric flux, the formula is given by
$$\Phi_E=EAcos\theta$$

For magnetic flux, the formula is similarly given by
$$\Phi_M=BAcos\theta$$

But would it not make more sense to describe flux as the number of field lines per unit area (i.e. in field diagrams)? Would the formulas then not become $\Phi_E=\frac{E}{A}cos\theta$ and
$\Phi_M=\frac{B}{A}cos\theta$?

Comment: Imagin a homogeneous field in space and you consider a certain (finite) surface A. The larger the surface or the field, the bigger the flux, hence the realtion E*A. The flux describe how much "field" in total you have. What you want to describe (E/A) is more like a field density which is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

$\Phi = \int \int F \; dA$. For some people the flux is $\Phi$. For some other people it is $F/t$, where $t$ is time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux. What you are proposing is some sort of field surface density. $E$ and $B$ are not quantities of "particles per time", so, for me it does not make *more* sense what you are proposing.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation for flux applies only in the case of a *uniform* electric field. That is, the part of $E$ normal to the surface $A$ is the same at all points on $A$.

The general expression for the total flux through a surface $A$ is

$$\Phi_E = \iint_A \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$$

If $E$ does not vary on the surface,

$$\Phi_E = \left( \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{\hat n} \right)\iint_A \mathrm{d}A = E\,A \, \mathrm{cos} \theta$$

This is simply how the electric flux is defined.

It seems like you're looking for the **divergence** of a vector field, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$. This could be understood as an indication of whether a point in a vector field is a sink or source and "how much" it is either. It can also be thought of as the field line density, which is what you're describing. Formally it is defined as

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \mathrm{lim}_{V \rightarrow 0} \iint_A \frac{\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{\hat n}}{|{V}|} \mathrm{d}A$$

where $V$ is the volume bounded by the closed surface $A$. In the present case, since $\mathrm{d}\Phi = \left( \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{\hat n} \right)\mathrm{d} A$ you can easily show that

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \mathrm{lim}_{V \rightarrow 0} \iint_A \frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi_E}{|{V}|}$$

This appears to be the **volume density** of $\Phi_E$. The limit there means that the divergence is just the value of the integral when you shrink down the volume of that surface to zero. This is pretty close to what you're looking for.

In fact, looking at the *differential* form of Gauss's law for the electric field, we see that

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

where $\rho$ is the charge density. Recalling that $\Phi_E = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$, where $Q$ is the charge, this is precisely what we would expect.